# Additional IGCSE Kinematics problem, Cambridge Oct/Nov 2011 0606/13

Tags: kinematics

**Hi I am having problems with this question below, still have no teacher to help due to corona:**

A particle moves in a straight line so that, *t* s after leaving a fixed point *O*, its velocity vms<sup>-1</sup> is given by v = 3e<sup>2t</sup> + 4*t*

Find the distance travelled by the particle in the third second

**I can't understand why the template answer says you need to subtract the displacement at 3 seconds by the displacement at 2 seconds.**

Answer (score 2):

The displacement at time $t$ is given by

$$s(t) =\int_0^t v(u)du$$

since $v(t)$ is always positive, during the third second the distance travelled is

$$s(3)-s(2)=\int_2^3 v(u)du$$